# Why Opera doesn't recognize Ubuntu font in my site?

Tags: css, ubuntu, font-face, opera, webfonts

I have changed the font of my blog in Wordpress (Genesis template) by uploading them to my own server, but Opera does not recognize Ubuntu font. The other browsers do.

This is the code I'm using:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'ubuntu-fonts-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '//fonts/ubuntu-stylesheet.css', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );
```

And this is part of CSS:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; src: url('fonts/ubuntu-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'); font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-display: swap; }
```

Can someone give me an idea to solve it?

Thanks,

I already tried double quote but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you saying it recognises it if you load it from elsewhere?

Comment: No, before I had Lora from Google Fonts and switched to Ubuntu font hosted locally on my server. The font works in all other browsers except Opera.

Comment: I asked because I was wondering what values Opera sets for swap and whether your server was slower.

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: Does the ubuntu font show up in dev tools network tab/fonts? Is the family applied when inspecting an element? If your css file is in fonts directory the font url in @font-face should be 'ubuntu-regular-webfont.woff'